# How to recover a brute-force protected user account?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic, user-accounts, login-control, brute-force

After a user has tried to login more often than the `consecutive_failed_logins_limit` and brute-force protection got enabled, what is the expected way to recover the account and reset the password? Does [Authlogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) expect manual resetting of the `failed_login_count` attribute in the `users` table by an administrator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `failed_login_ban_for` in the user session model to set the number of hours the user should be banned for (the default value is 2 hours).

Examples:

- To ban for a day: `failed_login_ban_for 24.hours`
- Permanent ban: `failed_login_ban_for 0`

Comment: This only sets the ban time, is there a way to reset a users ban manually if we wish to?

Comment: @riley Set the User's `failed_login_count` to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

You have the correct answer in your question.

Reset the failed_login_count value to 0

I have my consecutive_failed_logins_limit set to 5 and failed_login_ban_for 0.

I tried to log in with an incorrect password 6 times and then I got the account banned error message with the correct password or an incorrect one.

I manually reset the failed_login_count to 0 and then was able to log in using the correct password as normal.

I am planning to add a "unban" button to the user show view so an administrator can unban a user.